# Pandas - Пустая переменная X_test при попытке разделить данные на тестовый и тренировочный наборы

Tags: python, pandas

В датасете есть фича `DATA_TYPE` со значениями `TRAIN` и `TEST`, в общем по ним предлагается разбить данные на тренировочные и тестовые наборы.

Проблема в том, что при попытке создать тестовый набор `X_test = df[df.DATA_TYPE == 'TEST']` переменная `X_test` получается пустой, ну т.е. `X_test.shape = (0, 30)`.

В чем здесь может быть проблема?

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч в тегах указано 'pandas'

Comment: прошу прощения, вы читали описание? я там просто никакие алгоритмы не упоминал.

Comment: Фича =! метод, DATA_TYPE это column в датасете.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема заключалась в том, что значение `TEST` в фиче `DATA_TYPE` был с пробелом: `TEST` 
`X_test = df[df.DATA_TYPE == 'TEST ']` решило проблему.